# Problem to pass data model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this in view "Index":

```
<ul>
@foreach (var r in Model.Where(c => c.id_parent == null)) {
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(i => r.node.name)
        @if (r.node.children.Count > 0) { 
        <ul>
            @{Html.RenderPartial("aView", r.node);}
        </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

But getting this error on the RenderPartial line:

```
    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.arrangement_86479E2FE1ED6F9584881D169E310F3C37120A10A806A6CF640967CBCB017966',
but this dictionary requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PlanovaniZdroju.Models.arrangement]'.
```

How can I retype the r.node to IEnumerable? OR how else can I solve it?

Comment: What are you passing from controller?

Comment: @jimmy_keen
`public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var roots = db.roots;
            return View(roots.ToList());
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
<ul>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("aView", r.node.children);}
</ul>
```